# Anchos de marcos con Flexbox en IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Estoy con un código simple, comenzando a usar flexbox. Funciona perfecto en Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Edge, Opera, pero no en IE11.

Son unos marcos flexibles con imágenes y texto dentro de un área definida. En mi código solo uso `display: -webkit-flex; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;` y es suficiente. Algunas respuestas de Stackoverflow indican añadir más líneas de código, y nada. También encontré otro caso donde ponen cambiar todos los `max-width` `min-width`, `max-height` `min-height` por solo width o height. También lo probé y nada. Solo aparecen cuatro columnas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentro mi error, alguna ayuda? Mejor ver el snippet ampliado:

```css
html{
position:absolute;
font-size:1.15rem;
font-family:HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helvetica Neue Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;
font-weight:500;
line-height:1.2rem;
color: #62647b;
height: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 4rem;
background: gray;
}

#FRAME {display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -o-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-moz-flex-direction: row;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
-o-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-flow: row;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
-ms-flex-preferred-size:25%;
flex-basis:25%;
width: 25%;
float:left;
background: #FFFFFF;
justify-content: space-between;
box-sizing:border-box;
border: solid 0.1rem gray;
}

.IMAGECOL{-ms-flex-preferred-size:63%;
flex-basis:63%;
width:63%;
display: block;
position: relative;
float:left;
padding: 0.22rem;
left:0%;
}

.IMAGECOL img {
display:block;
width:100%;
}

.INFOCOL{-ms-flex-preferred-size:37%;
flex-basis:37%;
width:37%;
background: #e9e9f3;
float:left;
margin-top: 0.075rem;
margin-left: 0.075rem;
padding: 0.22rem;
max-height:100%;
}




/*TEXT*/
.SUJET {padding-right: .5em;
}
.COMPANY {color: #FF0004;
font-weight:800;
line-height:0.8rem}
.DATE {
line-height:1.35rem;
font-weight:300;}
.HEAD{font-size:4rem;
white-space:nowrap;
margin-bottom:1rem;
margin-bottom:1.5rem;
color: #747691;
}
.SUBHEAD{font-size:3rem;
/*white-space:nowrap;*/
margin-bottom:0.5rem;
color: #747691;
text-align:center;
line-height: 3rem;}
.NAME {margin-bottom:0.1rem;
font-weight:400;
font-size:2.5rem;
color: #b0b1c8;
line-height:0;
letter-spacing: 0.35rem;
}
.MAIN{font-size:1.144rem;
margin-bottom:1.25rem;
padding:0 2rem;
text-align:center;
color: #747691;
line-height: 2.2rem;
letter-spacing: 0.35rem;
}

.LINE {background: darkgray;
height: 1px;
margin-top: 6px;
margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.LINE2{background: darkgray;
height: 1px;
margin-top: 8px;
margin-bottom: 4px;}
```

```html
<div id="FRAME">
<div class="IMAGECOL"><a href="#">
   <img src="https://ptkotamas.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/kaolin-cold-drip-900ml-1.jpg?w=246&h=246&crop=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="INFOCOL"><span class="SUJET">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span><br><div class="LINE"></div><span class="COMPANY">FULLA</span><br><div class="LINE2"></div><span class="DATE">8/25/2017</span>
</div>
</div>

<div id="FRAME">
<div  class="IMAGECOL"><a href="#"><img src="https://ptkotamas.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/img_0928.jpg?w=246&h=246&crop=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="INFOCOL"><span class="SUJET">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span><br><div class="LINE"></div><span class="COMPANY">FULLA</span><br><div class="LINE2"></div><span class="DATE">8/25/2017</span>
</div>
</div>

<div id="FRAME">
<div class="IMAGECOL"><a href="#"><img src="https://ptkotamas.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/esrum-11.jpg?w=329&h=329&crop=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="INFOCOL"><span class="SUJET">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span><br><div class="LINE"></div><span class="COMPANY">FULLA</span><br><div class="LINE2"></div><span class="DATE">8/25/2017</span>
</div>
</div>

<div id="FRAME">
<div class="IMAGECOL"><a href=#">
<img src="https://ptkotamas.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/kaolin-cold-drip-900ml-1.jpg?w=246&h=246&crop=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="INFOCOL"><span class="SUJET">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span><br><div class="LINE"></div><span class="COMPANY">FULLA</span><br><div class="LINE2"></div><span class="DATE">8/25/2017</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No comprendo bien el error, ¿podría decir cual es el resultado que quiere?

Comment: En explorer 11 no se ven los marcos completos con la foto y el texto, se ven como en la imagen que puse: reducidos de anchura.

Comment: Ah, pero es un error directamente con IE 11, eso suele pasar mucho. Incruste [prefix](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/), seguro ésto lo soluciona. Si no le funciona, pues debe entonces crear todo por Javascript porque según [can i use](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), dice que IE10 e IE11 no soporta del todo, la propiedad `flexbox`, o css, pero sin esta propiedad.

Answer (score 1):

La solución es quitando el `position:absolut` del HTML (o el body). Me lo han dicho, yo no hubiese descubierto esto jamás!

Comment: publique la solución, para poder entender ¿qué estaba pasando?

Answer (score 0):

El internet explorer no soporta muy bien el flexbox, tiene soporte parcial para algunas funciones. https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox.

En IE11  para el tema del desplazamiento se usan los demás métodos disponibles debido a que el flexbox tiene un gran cantidad de bugs y problemas a la hora de implementarlo en el navegador.

Comment: Si. Yo lo vi relativamente simple al crearlo, pero luego, como siempre, el tema de las compatibilidades es un planeta aparte. Igual para este caso me pasaron una solución que publico abajo. Gracias.